# Laravel 5.2 one to one relationship gives an error mesg "SQLSTATE[23000]:" after form submission

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have created two tables in laravel 5.2 one is called "users" and the other is called "artists_details" and they have a one to one relationship. the schema of the users table is as follows

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->boolean('admin')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('manager')->nullable();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and the schema of the artists table is as follows

```
Schema::create('artists_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('artists_image_path');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('phone_no');
        $table->integer('passport');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->string('county');
        $table->string('facebook_name');
        $table->string('twitter_handle');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('alternative_email');
        $table->string('website');
        $table->text('biography');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('users')
              ->onDelete('CASCADE');

    });
```

I have indicated the relationship in the models as follows 
User model

```
public function artists_relation()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\artists_details_model');
}
```

and on the artists_details_model as follows

```
public function user_artist_details()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

The php code that handles the form submission in the controller is as follows

```
public function artists_details_store(Request $request)
{
  $input = \Request::all();
  $file = $request->file('file');

   $name = time(). $file->getClientOriginalName();

   $file->move('artists_image/photo', $name);



  $artists_input = new artists_details_model;

  $artists_input->artists_image_path  = 'artists_image/photo/'. $name;
  $artists_input->name                = $input['name'];
  $artists_input->phone_no            = $input['phone_no'];
  $artists_input->passport            = $input['passport'];
  $artists_input->city                = $input['city'];
  $artists_input->county              = $input['county'];
  $artists_input->facebook_name       = $input['facebook_name'];
  $artists_input->twitter_handle      = $input['twitter_handle'];
  $artists_input->email               = $input['email'];
  $artists_input->alternative_email   = $input['alternative_email'];
  $artists_input->website             = $input['website'];
  $artists_input->biography           = $input['biography'];
  $artists_input->save();


    return redirect('create');
}
```

When i click on the submit button i get the following error message

> QueryException in Connection.php line 669:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

I cant seem to see where i am going wrong or what seems to be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the table **'artists_details'** you have mentioned as

`$table->foreign('user_id')
              ->references('id')
              ->on('users')`

So whenever you try to save the details in the 'artists_details' you need to provide the 'user_id' without which the information will not get saved.

Either you need to pass the 'UserID' as a hidden parameter or if the UserID is saved in the Session, then you need to retrieve it from the Session.

Comment: Thanks Vinod Tigadi for the fast response. i decided to pass the authenticated user_id from the users table and store it in a variable, which inserts the user id in the 'artists_details' table as a hidden parameter and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad that I could help you. Good Luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to be including the foreign key {user_id} on your form

Comment: the foreign key constrain is include. but i have the solution, thanks for the help though.